# One of two identical NICs is unclaimed after disconnecting with applet

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have AsRock X399 Taichi motherboard, with two ethernet cards and one Wi-Fi. I used a default network applet from Ubuntu Mate 18.04 to disconnect from the ethernet (to only have Wi-Fi connection) and it caused the network card to be unclaimed.

I’ve tried removing all udev rules from `/etc/udev/rules.d` and reloading the kernel’s module for the card, but to no success. I also cannot add it manually using said applet (it doesn’t show that card) nor can I `ifconfig up` it.

Both NICs work just fine on LiveCD.

`lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:efa00000-efa1ffff ioport:6000(size=32) memory:efa20000-efa23fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 10
       serial: 28:c6:3f:15:46:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.100.132 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:104 memory:ef900000-ef901fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:64:1f:1c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 ip=192.168.8.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:ef800000-ef81ffff ioport:5000(size=32) memory:ef820000-ef823fff
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel modules: igb
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
08:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX8112 x1 Lane PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge [10b5:8112] (rev aa)
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo modprobe -rv igb` and `sudo modprobe -v igb` to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Yes. It doesn’t. I suspect that the applet added some config setting, which I can’t find, that turned off the NIC for good.

Comment: Nothing unusual in `/etc/networking/interfaces` I suppose?

Comment: I assume you meant `/etc/network/interfaces`, if so → `auto lo` \n `iface lo inet loopback` (used \n as a symbol of new line, since comments are one-line-only).